# i've tried something insane and it worked, why? (code: `class Foo <GenericFoo extends Foo <GenericFoo>> { /* ... */ }`

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Like in the topic, I've tried something which in my humble opinion is insane. Why did it work?

Let's omit why and how I ended in a position where I needed/tried such code… *cough* bad design? *cough*…

Simplistic example:

```
class Foo <
    GenericFoo extends Foo <GenericFoo> // here !!!
> {
    public readonly msg: string;

    public constructor (msg: string) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }
}

class Bar
    extends
        Foo <Bar>
{
    public constructor (msg: string) {
        super (msg)
    }
}

// just proving to myself that class funcions "corectly"...
const foo = new Foo ("foo");
const bar = new Bar ("bar");
console.log(foo.msg);
console.log(bar.msg);
```

Why didn't it throw an infinite-recursion-error or sth similar?

I am starting to even doubt myself if my confusion here is justified.
The whole idea of `class Base` taking `class Child` as its generic parameter seems fundamentally wrong to me.

Is such code common in “bigger” projects? Does it indicate bad design?

TLDR:
please throw some fancy terms/vocabulary related to this code, so I can read more about the subject.

Comment: the designers of typescript are very smart and they have lots of tricks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works because that's a perfectly legitimate way to use generics. In fact, it not only works, but it's a well-known pattern commonly known as the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), or more formally, F-Bound Polymorphism.

It's a pattern commonly used in builders and other classes where many method calls are often chained together, and where these classes often have different subclasses providing different subsets of methods for different parts of the chain.

This allows subclasses to inherit methods from the superclasses without losing the subclass type:

```js
interface CollectionBuilder<
    Coll, Elem, Self extends CollectionBuilder<Coll, Elem, Self>
> {
    build(): Coll
    add(e: Elem): Self // Instead of CollectionBuilder
    filter(fn: (e: Elem) => boolean): Self // Instead of CollectionBuilder
}

interface SortedCollectionBuilder<
    Coll, Elem, Self extends SortedCollectionBuilder<Coll, Elem>
> extends CollectionBuilder<Coll, Elem, Self> {
    setSortingMode(comparator: Comparator, ordering: Ordering): Self
}
```

In the above example, `SortedCollectionBuilder` extends `CollectionBuilder` by adding the `setSortingMode` method. Without the CRTP pattern, the methods inherited from `CollectionBuilder` would either have to be overridden to update the return type to `SortedCollectionBuilder`, or all the methods in `SortedCollectionBuilder` would have to be used first since the rest would fall back to returning `CollectionBuilder`, losing access to `setSortingMode` and whatever else might exist.

(Note, for this *specific* case, TypeScript offers the `this` type that could be used instead. However, that only covers a very narrow subset of cases where CRTP may be useful.)